# Let's col[lab]orate on a plan for this tag!

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

## This is a discussion. DO NOT burninate this tag right now

We have a [lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lab) tag. Here's its tag description:

> Lab is a simple test utility for node.

Except... it isn't being used that way. I've seen it get used for

- Questions pertaining to labs at school (questions about homework/projects from school)
- L*a*b color space
- JupyterLab

Ideally, a tag should only refer to one thing. Let's go through the burnination criteria:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It describes the questions to a degree, but this tag is ambiguous as it can refer to multiple unique topics.

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Likely yes. Jupyter is on-topic, and questions about the color format *may* be on-topic. Homework questions aren't off-topic, per se, but that would be [a Meta Tag](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/), so it shouldn't be a tag.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

Maybe? Probably yes for Jupyter and the color space, not really for homework questions

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Nope

Thoughts on what we should do with this tag and/or if it should get burninated?

---

Credit to [@rgettman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1707091/rgettman) for the title pun

Comment: Let's col[lab]orate on a plan for this tag.  Some require removal, others require retagging.

Comment: Let's tidy up the [lab]

Answer (score 24):

## This is a proposal, not an invitation to go and burninate this tag or mass-retag questions

I propose that

- For questions where it is being used to refer to a school lab, the tag is removed
- <del>A dedicated tag is created for the L*a*b color space (if one doesn't already exist), and questions are re-tagged to use that when appropriate</del> Questions about the L*a*b are re-tagged to [cielab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cielab) per [@Erik A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-a)'s comment
- We already have tags for [jupyter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter) and [jupyter-lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jupyter-lab), so questions can be re-tagged to those as needed
- A new tag is created for the test utility. Or maybe this tag should be retained for that Node.js project, and a tag warning gets added. As [@Erik A](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/7296893/erik-a) suggested, [node-lab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/node-lab) could work well

Comment: We already have a tag for the LAB color space: [cielab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cielab). For the current tag, I recommend node-lab, tag warnings don't work

Comment: From experience, tags with a generic name are consistently misused, and no amount of warnings will work. So you'll need [tag:node-lab] and to ban [tag:lab] so nobody can keep using it.